# ¿Como puedo mostrar solo un slide en version mobile usando carusel?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo el carusel de bootstrap 4 armado de la siguiente manera y actualmente en la versión de escritorio muestra 3, pero en versión mobile se ven 3 elementos en vertical y necesito que se ve solo 1.

Como lo puedo configurar para que se vea solo uno, intente agregar las clases de col-xs-12, pero no tuve éxito.

Estoy tratando de configurar alguna función javascript que me permita mostrar solo un elemento.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="0">
                    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>   
                    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 receta">
                                    <div class="card mb-4">
                                        <a href="canelones-jurel.html">
                                            <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" src="img/receta1.png" alt="">
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="card-body">
                                        <a href="canelones-jurel.html">
                                                <p class="card-text">Nombre Producto</p>
                                                <img class="star" src="img/estrellas.png" alt="valoración">
                                                <p class="card-text">Valoración</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 receta">
                                    <div class="card mb-4">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" src="img/receta2.png" alt="">
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="card-body">
                                        <a href="#">
                                                <p class="card-text">Nombre Producto</p>
                                                <img class="star" src="img/estrellas.png" alt="valoración">
                                                <p class="card-text">Valoración</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 receta">
                                    <div class="card mb-4">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" src="img/receta3.png" alt="">
                                        </a>

                                        <div class="card-body">
                                        <a href="#">
                                                <p class="card-text">Nombre Producto</p>
                                                <img class="star" src="img/estrellas.png" alt="valoración">
                                                <p class="card-text">Valoración</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Carousel controls -->
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev arrow-left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next arrow-rigth" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Estás implementando mal el carousel, empezado porque debes tener un `.carousel-item` individual para cada `.card`, veo 1 solo. Así tal cual, no tienes un carousel, lo que tienes son tres columnas, nada más. Debes reorganizar la estructura de tu código. Revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/